# default sharepoint theme - where is it?

Tags: 2010, theme

The marketing department at my job likes the default SharePoint 2010 theme, but wants me to change the font. I thought that I would just make a copy of the default theme and edit that file, but I don't see anything called default.thmx in the 14 hive.

Is there actually a default.thmx? Or do I need to create a new theme that approximates the default theme colors and uses the requested font? Or is there another solution?

Comment: did you find a solution for this? I too would like to save the default theme. Cheers.

Comment: @foocode No, I didn't find a way to save the original theme. Maybe that is how I should have phrased the question originally.

Comment: The Default Theme is not a theme at all. It just uses the default colors/fonts specified in the CSS that would normally be replaced with the Theme comments. Unfortunately, there are way more color options in the default theme than possible in any custom theme meaning just getting those colors and specifying different fonts won't work. You can find more info on my blog here: http://thechriskent.com/2012/02/29/sharepoint-2010-default-theme-colors/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the default header and body fonts in **Site Settings** > **Site Theme** (under the Look and Feel section) from the **Site Actions** menu.

Someone else might have an alternative approach if you want to do something more finely-grained.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of that, but it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: You asked "Or is there another solution"...I offered up another solution. And it wasn't obvious that you knew of the configuration as a) You didn't mention it and b) I'm not sure why you would go to the trouble of physically altering the theme if you can make the necessary changes via config.

Comment: Sorry, you are right.

Comment: One point though, when customizing the default theme, for some reason SharePoint doesn't keep all the default colors (links and background colors at the top of the page change). So I had to go back in and use a color sampling tool to get the original colors from a site I hadn't re-themed, and then apply those to the themed site.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd be able to get any fine-grained customisation re: fonts by setting up an override CSS file. As a collection admin, under Site Settings -> Master Page you can specify an alternate CSS URL (I uploaded a .css file to the site assets folder and linked to that).

You can then specify your overriding CSS rules (including font changes) in this file and they'll be included on each page. This CSS is included after the default so it take priority... Only styling set within the masterpage markup should have higher precedence.

It's how I've been going about customising the default look and feel.